Drag and drop to my NAS
I'm running ubuntu Ubuntu 23.10.
I've created a NAS using OpenMediaVault v7 on a raspberry pi, creating a SMB/CIFS share.
I've permanently mounted the SMB share using fstab and it works wonderfully. The problem is that I can't drag and drop a file from my system/ubuntu to the NAS. I think its a simple fix since I can use the command line to copy a file to the NAS, but it does require root privileges.

Please post the line you are using to mount the share in fstab.

//10.15.111.134/nas /media/nas cifs credentials=/home/l3ek/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8  0  0

mount.cifs creates a virtual filesystem that by default mounts with owner = root and write permissions only to root.
One way around this is to take possession of the mount by specifying yourself as owner: uid=l3ek
Unmount the share:
sudo umount /media/nas

Change the mount in fstab and add the uid option:
//10.15.111.134/nas /media/nas cifs credentials=/home/l3ek/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,uid=l3ek 0 0

Save fstab and remount:
sudo mount -a


Caveat: Make sure to run systemctl daemon-reload after modifying fstab these days.
